# Sending email without Java in R

Tags: r, email

How to send HTML format email in R, without the need for Java?

The package mailR is no longer usable as it is dependent on Java. What are the alternate packages?

Note:
The following worked well with mailR and trying to replicate the same.

```
send.mail(from = fromEmailAddress,
          to = mailTo,
          subject = subjectDetailed ,
          body = bodyToSend,
          html = TRUE,
          smtp = list(host.name = hostname, port = 25), 
          send = TRUE 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works.

```
library(sendmailR)

msg = mime_part(bodyToSend)
msg[["headers"]][["Content-Type"]] = "text/html"

sendmail(mailFrom,mailTo,subject, msg, control=list(smtpServer= "smtpserver"))
```

Answer (score 1):

**blastula**, **Microsoft365R** are couple of great packages for HTML emails and also support Rmarkdown report emails

[blastula]
https://github.com/rstudio/blastula

[Microsoft365R]
https://github.com/Azure/Microsoft365R

Comment: I am not sure how to convert the following using blastula.

Comment: send.mail(from = fromEmailAddress,
          to = mailTo,
          subject = subjectDetailed ,
          body = bodyToSend,
          html = TRUE,
          smtp = list(host.name = hostname, port = 25), 
          send = TRUE 
)

Comment: With blastula, creating the credential file seems to be difficult with hostname (Firm name instead of gmail / yahoo email)